# Cargar combobox seleccionado desde sql server utilizando entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, entity-framework

Tengo una tabla trabajador que guarda los registros relacionados con trabajador como `rut-nombre-sexo-estado civil`.

Sexo y estado civil se guarda como `1=masculino- 2=femenino`.

Esto lo realizo a través de un combobox.

Lo que necesito realizar es que al realizar una búsqueda del trabajador me cargue el combobox seleccionado automáticamente.

Mi código para cargar el combobox es el siguiente;

```
public void llenasexo()
{
    var sexo = db.TB_Sexo.ToList();
    if (sexo.Count > 0)
    {
        combo_sexo.DataSource = sexo;
        combo_sexo.DisplayMember = "DescripcionSexo";
        combo_sexo.ValueMember = "Idsexo";
        if (combo_sexo.Items.Count > 1)
        {
            combo_sexo.SelectedIndex = -1;
        } 
    }
}
```

Y mi código para extraer los datos es:

```
 TB_Trabajador trabajador = (from q in db.TB_Trabajador where q.Rut == txt_rut1.Text select q).First();
        trabajador.Rut = lbl_rut.Text;
        trabajador.Nombres = txt_nombre.Text;
        trabajador.Sexo = combo_sexo.ValueMember("idsexo");
```

El error esta al tratar de cargar el valor seleccionado al combobox sexo donde muestra que `valuemember` no es invocable.

Comment: Trabajas en Windows Forms? o en que? edita la pregunta y agrega ese dato porfavor

Comment: si trabajo en Windows Forms.

Comment: No me queda del todo claro, lo que queres hacer es seleccionar la opción por defecto que traes de la base de datos en el combo?

Comment: si si exactamente ejemplo: tengo un usuario que es 2=femenino y al momento de extraer el idsexo que en este caso seria 2 el combobox debería seleccionarse automáticamente como femenino.

Answer (score 0):

para extraer los datos debes usar la propiedad SelectedValue

```
    trabajador.Sexo = Convert.ToInt32(combo_sexo.SelectedValue); //Hacemos un convert debido aque el valor de SelectedValue siempre será un object
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que tenes es lógico, se da porque estas intentando tratar la [propiedad](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) [`ValueMember`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember?view=netframework-4.7.2) como si fuese un [método](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods).

Para seleccionar una opción de tu [`ComboBox`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=netframework-4.7.2), basta con setear la propiedad [`SelectedValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SelectedValue);k(vs.objectbrowser);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
combo_sexo.SelectedValue = trabajador.Sexo
```

De esta manera, el [`ComboBox`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=netframework-4.7.2) se seleccionará en el valor almacenado en `trabajador.Sexo`

En el caso contrario, cuando necesites obtener el valor seleccionado, podes usar la misma [propiedad](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties), por lo que remplazarías

```
trabajador.Sexo = combo_sexo.ValueMember("idsexo");
```

por (la conversión es necesaria porque [`SelectedValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SelectedValue);k(vs.objectbrowser);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) es de tipo [`object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/object?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(object_CSharpKeyword)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue).

```
trabajador.Sexo = Convert.ToInt32(combo_sexo.SelectedValue);
```

De esta manera, `trabajador.Sexo` va a valer `1` o `2`